# UML how to represent JSON file

Tags: json, uml

Quick question:
I'm loading in a JSON file that is stored inside of my repository. How do I represent the JSON file, if it's needed at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the object you just show it as Artifact (p. 654 UML 2.6):

> An Artifact represents some (usually reifiable) item of information that is used or produced by a software development process or by operation of a system. Examples of Artifacts include model files, source files, scripts, executable files, database tables, development deliverables, word-processing documents, and mail messages.

It is shown as rectangle like a class with a "file-like" decorator top right. P. 655:

> An Artifact is presented using an ordinary Class rectangle with the keyword «artifact». Alternatively, it may be depicted by an icon (such as the document icon shown in Figure 19.9). Optionally, the underlining of the name of an artifact instance may be omitted, as the context is assumed to be known to users.

If you need the structure you would rather show it as class with the single attributes contained inside.